# Remove first n from each group

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas data frame with the following structure:

```
idx | flag | val
----------------
0   | a    | 17
1   | a    | 18
2   | a    | 17
3   | a    | 14
4   | a    | 17
5   | b    | 7
6   | b    | 8
7   | b    | 7
8   | b    | 7
```

How can I remove the first n values for each flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

realized an answer while writing the question:

You can group by flags, count the the number of occurrences of that flag sequentially, then filter based on that count:

```
df_filt = df[df.groupby('flag ').cumcount('flag ') > n]
```